# AJAX request's status pending unless async turned off

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and have a function that uploads a file to s3. The majority of the time while I test it, the PUT upload request returns `pending` status and never resolves. The file also fails to upload when this happens. However when I use `async: false`, everything works fine, and the pending status turns to a 200 shortly.

I'm wondering if anyone knows the cause of this issue for async requests, as using `async: false` is not a viable solution for me. We are making the request from the Chrome's event. Here's the code:

```js
$.get(url + 'videos/generate_s3_for_chrome', { content_type: 'video/webm' })
  .done(function(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: data.presigned_url,
    method: "PUT",
    contentType: "video/webm",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    //async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'video/webm');
    },
    data: file,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success', data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems like a library or server api question. Can you reproduce with fetch?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: At a guess this is being called in asynchronous code that closes the popup before the PUT completes, but it's impossible to be sure as it's the code that's calling this that we need to see. I would add though that in a Chrome extension you should use `fetch` and you shouldn't need jQuery.

Comment: @Keith thanks for suggestion, I tried using fetch and have the exact same issue. The PUT requests result in a pending response that never resolves.

Comment: @parameter yeah, `fetch` is better than `$.ajax`, but it's not your fix here. The problem is that the surrounding code is terminating before the callback fires (that's why forcing sync works - it makes the calling code wait). To help you with that we need to see your calling code in context.

Comment: @Keith thanks I updated my question to include the surrounding code, I figured there shouldn't be an issue because I am making the PUT request within the .done function of the GET.